# Showing that the stopped filtration $\mathcal{F}_{s \vee t} = \mathcal{F}_s \cup \mathcal{F}_t$

Tags: probability-theory, stopping-times, filtrations

Show that $\mathcal{F}_{s \vee t} = \mathcal{F}_s \cup \mathcal{F}_t$ where $\mathcal{F}_{s}, \mathcal{F}_{t}$ and $\mathcal{F}_{s \vee t}$ are stopping time sigma fields.

Let's suppose that S > T and so $\mathcal{F}_s > \mathcal{F}_t$

> $\mathcal{F}_s \cup \mathcal{F}_t \subset \mathcal{F}_s$

This is obvious since, due to the fact that this is an union, $\mathcal{F}_s \cup \mathcal{F}_t$ is $\mathcal{F}_s$ **OR** $\mathcal{F}_t$ so it's in the case it would be in $F_T$, it will also be in $F_s$.

> $\mathcal{F}_s \subset \mathcal{F}_s \cup \mathcal{F}_t$

So:

1. Shouldn't the last be also trivial?
2. In the only case I would have had the intersection of the two sigma algebra instead of the union, the only thing that needs to be shown is that $F_s \in F_t$?

Comment: the statament as written $\mathcal{F}_{s \vee t} = \mathcal{F}_s \cup \mathcal{F}_t$ is false, as the RHS is not a $\sigma $-algebra, except the case where $\mathcal{F}_s \subset \mathcal{F}_t$ or $\mathcal{F}_t\subset \mathcal{F}_s$

Comment: Well, but I one is surely smaller than the other so there's the inclusion so there can be the union of the two sigma algebras.

Comment: but then there is nothing to prove, by example if $S\leqslant T$ then $S\,\lor\, T=T$ and so $\mathcal{F}_{S\,\lor\, T}=\mathcal{F}_T$, and also $\mathcal{F}_S \cup \mathcal{F}_T=\mathcal{F}_T$ because $\mathcal{F}_S\subset \mathcal{F}_T$ as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4614097/173262)

Comment: When instead dealing with the Intersection of the sigma algebra will bring to a similar exercise as if I would have the minimum of the stopped sigma fields?

Comment: Try showing instead that $\mathcal F_{s\vee t} =\sigma(\mathcal F_s\cup\mathcal F_t)$.

Comment: Well that' basically what I tried in my solution